# How to connect and send msg to Fix server from camel

Tags: apache-camel, fix-protocol

I need to creat such route: 
Parse csv file -> create Fix String -> send it to external FIX server.
So. How I can estabilish connection in camel xml configuration and send it with camel-quickfx module?
I have such code:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:processOneLine2"/>
        <bean ref="orderBean" method="createFixMessage"/>
        <to uri="quickfix-client:META-INF/quickfix/client.cfg"/>
    </route>
```

And configuration:

```
    [DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
SenderCompID=TW


[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=ARCA
StartTime=12:30:00
EndTime=23:30:00
HeartBtInt=20
SocketConnectPort=3313
SocketConnectHost=localhost
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
```

But I get such error:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[quickfix-client:META-INF/quickfix/client.cfg] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[Fr
>   om[direct:processOneLine2]] -> [Bean[ref:or... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: quickfix-client://META-INF/quickfix/client.cfg due to: No component found with scheme: quickfix-client

Comment: Is your question just around how to connect to a server using camel-quickfix, or the whole route?

Comment: Only how to connect to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message you need to define:

```
<bean id="quickfix-client" 
      class="org.apache.camel.component.quickfixj.QuickfixjComponent">
  <property name="messageFactory" ref=".."/> <!-- DefaultMessageFactory -->
  <property name="messageStoreFactory" ref=".."/> <!-- MemoryStoreFactory -->
  <property name="logFactory" ref=".."/> <!-- ScreenLogFactory -->
</bean>
```

The properties themselves are QuickFIX/J classes, you'll need to refer back to the [QuickFIX/J documentation](http://www.quickfixj.org/documentation/) to work out how to set them up in a way that's right for you. The comments above are the default classes in the `quickfixj.` package that are used by the component in the [unit tests](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-quickfix/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/quickfixj/QuickfixjComponentTest.java).